# unique_ptr is not deleted after calling reset

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

This is my minimal, reproducible example

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


class BaseClass {
public:
    void do_func() {
        while(true) {
            std::cout << "doing stuff" << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
        
    }
};

int main() {
    auto obj = std::make_unique<BaseClass>();
    std::thread t(&BaseClass::do_func, obj.get());
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "reset called!" << std::endl;
    obj.reset();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "going out of scope" << std::endl;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the object to be deleted after reset is called. Even the code cannot exit because the while loop is blocking, which is understandable. I need to delete the object after a particular event, and cannot wait till the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope. If I change the `do_func` to

```cpp
void do_func() {
    std::cout << "doing stuff" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
}
```

then it is the expected behaviour.

**Edit:**
Based on your comments I have updated my code to

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


class BaseClass {
public:

    BaseClass() : x(1) {
        dummy = std::make_shared<SomeClass>();
    }

    void do_func() {
        while(true) {
            std::cout << "doing stuff " << dummy->do_stuff(x) << std::endl;
            x++;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
private:
    int x;
    class SomeClass {
    public:
        int do_stuff(int x) {
            return x * x;
        }
    }; 
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> dummy;
};

int main() {
    auto obj = std::make_unique<BaseClass>();
    std::thread t(&BaseClass::do_func, obj.get());
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "reset called!" << std::endl;
    obj.reset();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "going out of scope" << std::endl;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

And now the function does print garbage values. Does that mean I need to explicitly delete `dummy` in the destructor?

Comment: You delete the object while the thread using the object still is running. That is kind of bad and will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: let's say I have a destructor which does the proper clean-up, but still `reset` should delete the object right?

Comment: And joining a thread will block until the thread function exits. You need some way to tell the thread to exit, for example an atomic boolean variable.

Comment: Are you sure the object is not destructed ? Your while loop will not stop just because the object is destructed.

Comment: You cannot solve synchronization problem this way. You need to communicate to the object that it should stop working somehow, e.g. with condition variables. What you are doing is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Actually my problem is not the "undefined behaviour". Maybe that is not captured well in the minimal example. The main problem is that the object is not deleted after reset.

Comment: On most runtimes, as `do_func` doesn't access any member variables it will continue to work when the object is destructed this is however undefined behaviour according to the standard

Comment: But the object *is* deleted and destructed. You just don't notice it because as mentioned it won't stop the function from running.

Comment: Deleting an object with no contents is likely to be very hard to notice. But its memory will be handed back to the system to be reused, even if you still keep accessing it through your looping function.

Comment: btw: Member functions are NOT part of the object, they are part of the `class`. So they never get deleted, they just keep running while accessing deleted (invalidated) memory.

Comment: I have updated the code now.

Comment: I managed to get a more "satysfying" UB result by adding a vector to `do_work` function. You can see the object goes wild immediately after unique_ptr is reset and it crashes soon after that: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Oc9ZmVaadQJwOqK7

Comment: @harsh *Does that mean I need to explicitly delete dummy in the destructor?* No. It means that you using this object after it is deleted. This is UB and you cannot do anything to change that. Whatever you do in destructor, the result will be the same - you are using a destroyed object. To stop the work, you need to synchronize main thread with the worker, and this is not done by destroying worker object. It is done with atomic variables, condition variables or other similar semapfore objects.

Comment: try to explain what is the purpose of the code. Your interpretation is off (`reset` does destroy the object), but it is difficult to help, because it is not clear what parts of the example are part of the problem you are trying to solve and what is part of your attempted solution

Comment: @harsh You keep saying the object wasn't destroyed. Why do you say that? What evidence do you have that the object wasn't destroyed? Add some logging to the destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to synchronize these two threads would be to use [`std::atomic_bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

```
#include <atomic>

class BaseClass {
public:
    std::atomic_bool shouldContinueWork = true;

    void do_func() {
        while(shouldContinueWork) {
            std::cout << "doing stuff" << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }

    }
};

int main() {
    auto obj = std::make_unique<BaseClass>();
    std::thread t(&BaseClass::do_func, obj.get());
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    obj->shouldContinueWork = false; //the thread will not do anything more after this, but the sleep will need to end on it's own
    std::cout << "stopping work!" << std::endl;

    // do not remove the object before join is called - you don't know if it will be still accessed from the other thread or not
    // obj.reset();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "going out of scope" << std::endl;
    t.join();
    // here it is safe to remove the `obj`, main thread is surely the only thread that accesses it
    // (but it goes out of scope anyway)
    return 0;
}
```

This solution doesn't take into account stopping the work midway (i.e. whole loop iteration must always be performed) and is generally prone to having a few more or less iterations of work - it should be precise enough when you have sleep of 1s, but with smaller sleep it won't guarantee any exact number of iterations, take that into account. [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) can be used for more precise control of thread synchronization.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for all your quick responses! Let me know if this is a good solution

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


class BaseClass {
public:

    BaseClass() : x(1) {
        dummy = std::make_shared<SomeClass>();
    }

    virtual ~BaseClass() {
        dummy.reset();
    }

    void do_func() {
        while(dummy) {
            std::cout << "doing stuff " << dummy->do_stuff(x) << std::endl;
            x++;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
private:
    int x;
    class SomeClass {
    public:
        int do_stuff(int x) {
            return x * x;
        }
    }; 
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> dummy;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {

};

int main() {
    auto obj = std::make_unique<DerivedClass>();
    std::thread t(&BaseClass::do_func, obj.get());
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "reset called!" << std::endl;
    obj.reset();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "going out of scope" << std::endl;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The behaviour is now as expected.

Comment: This is still undefined behavior -- you're still accessing the object after it has been destroyed.  To be safe, you need to call t.join() before calling obj.reset().  To not hang, you'll need to do something else to get do_func to exit (so t.join() will return).

Comment: As I wrote in comment above - this changes absolutely nothing. `*obj` is destroyed when `obj.reset()` is called. Destroying of this object will not stop any thread. It does not prevent you from using the object after it is destroyed. You need to properly synchronize your threads instead of trying to work around that.

Comment: Could you please show an example? I am not getting what you mean by "synchronize the thread" in this context.

Comment: on my system this runs forever.